Is there meaning to the authors' use of “their" synagogue in comparison to “the" Temple?
Is there something the authors intend to help the reader understand in several uses of “their” synagogue in comparison to “the” Temple?
The word “their” is the possessive form of the third-person plural pronoun “they”; meaning “belonging to them”.
When referencing the temple, it’s often mentioned preceded by a definite article “the” which suggests uniqueness. To my understanding, the temple is not referred to as "their" temple.
Here are examples of “their" synagogue (KJV)
Matthew 12:9 And when he was departed thence, he went into their synagogue: nd, behold, there was a man which had his hand withered. And they asked him, saying, Is it lawful to heal on the sabbath days? that they might accuse him.
Matthew 13:54 And when he was come into his own country, he taught them in their synagogue, insomuch that they were astonished, and said, Whence hath this man this wisdom, and these mighty works?
Mark 1:23 And there was in their synagogue a man with an unclean spirit; and he cried out, (24) Saying, Let us alone; what have we to do with thee, thou Jesus of Nazareth? art thou come to destroy us? I know thee who thou art, the Holy One of God.
Uses  of “the” temple.(KJV)
Matthew 21:12 And Jesus went into the temple of God, and cast out all them that sold and bought in the temple, and overthrew the tables of the moneychangers, and the seats of them that sold doves
Matthew 23:21 And whoso shall swear by the temple, sweareth by it, and by him that dwelleth therein.
Mark 12:35 And Jesus answered and said, while he taught in the temple, How say the scribes that Christ is the son of David?
In the gospel of Matthew originally written in Hebrew, the similar approach to the phrase is used but the words are different. The phrases used are: “their house of assembly” in comparison to “the Sanctuary”.

The original Greek word has many related meanings. E.g. Matthew 2:11 has "And when they were come into the house, they saw the young child with Mary his mother, and fell down, and worshipped him: and when they had opened their treasures, they presented unto him gifts; gold, and frankincense, and myrrh.". Three different uses of G846 in the one verse. There must be some grammatical argument about why it is used so often in front of "synagogues" (perhaps "a synagogue" is too vague and "the synagogue" is too specific?).

It may be a similar matter to Jesus saying 'your law', not 'the' law. John 10:34.

One TempleThroughout Israeli history into Jewish history of the first century, there was only one Temple allowed, where LORD God placed His name: the Temple of the LORD. (Deuteronomy 16:5-6)
So it would be inappropriate to speak of their Temple. It was the unique prerogative of the LORD Himself where He alone was the focus---and the worship was prescribed by Him:  Certain sacrifices, certain Holy Days, certain access by priests, certain rituals.
Many SynagoguesHowever, when dealing with synagogues, we're dealing with an animal of a different stripe! A wholly different set up and organization. In fact, the "synagogue" was a rather late invention in the history of Old Testament Israel! Scholars say the Ezra, after the return from Exile, instituted this meeting house.
Each synagogue had a group of rulers overseeing it, and these are mentioned in the New Testament at various times: Ruler of the synagogue, someone in charge of charity, teachers (rabbis), etc. [See Alfred Edershem, Life and Times of Jesus the Messiah]
These synagogues provided a place of worship on the Sabbaths, for worshippers throughout Judea and Galilee.  [Travel to the Jerusalem Temple of the LORD was an arduous journey, and only done on special occasions.] "Their synagogue" was a conveniently located place of worship.
But for those who lived in Jerusalem's metropolis, there were many synagogues dotting the landscape. And it was natural for clans or Jews originating from different lands to gather in one synagogue.  So of the hundreds of synagogues in Jerusalem, each would be called by their name. For example, "the synagogue of the Greeks," "the synagogue of Egyptians," etc. So their synagogue would be an appropriate nomenclature.
Also, a certain school of a notable rabbis would congregate in one synagogue---and it would be their synagogue.. That is, the synagogue would be known by the name of the leading scholarly rabbi. (Gamaliel, Hillel, Shammai, etc.)
In fact, synagogues were known to compete for worshippers by having famous speakers teach on the sabbath! They were often competing for congregates---and their money! [According to the Jewish Encyclopaedia, some of the competition among the Pharisees led to violence! Note that violence was not uncommon nor unfamiliar to Jesus and the early Christians. Note Saul's demeanor before salvation.]
So their synagogue is quite appropriate when describing any Jewish synagogue. It was man's organization, with their rules, their officers (not priests), their teachings (which was extremely legalistic; Matthew 23),and their understanding of salvation.
The Temple of the LORD, on the other hand was the Father's House, not theirs! [Certainly not theirs to corrupt and make into "a den of robbers."]

+1 ... small correction: "Israeli" describes the modern state of Israel. "Israelite" refers to the ancient nation/people.

The Law of Moses allowed only on Temple where sacrifices could be offered.  The synagogues were for worship and religious education, not sacrifices.

5 You may not offer the Passover sacrifice within any of your towns that the LORD your God is giving you, 6 but at the place that the LORD your God will choose, to make his name dwell in it, there you shall offer the Passover sacrifice, in the evening at sunset,...
(Deut. 16:5–6, ESV2016)

The synagogue (בֵּית כְּנֶסֶת), not mentioned in the Law or the Old Testament, gave them a religious center of worship without sacrifice.  Perhaps "their" because they were instituted by the Jews rather than God.   Note in Matt. 4:23; 9:35; 10:17; Luke 4:15 not only is their plural but also synagogue. Also note house of assembly בֵּית כְּנֶסֶת is how you say synagogue in Hebrew.

And he went throughout all Galilee, teaching in their synagogues [ἐν ταῖς συναγωγαῖς αὐτῶν] and proclaiming the gospel of the kingdom and healing every disease and every affliction among the people.
(Matt. 4:23, ESV2016)

As far as Matthew writing his Gospel in Herew, Irenaeus in the second century wrote:

Matthew also issued a written Gospel among the Hebrews in their own dialect, while Peter and Paul were preaching in Rome and laying the foundation of the Church. After their departure, Mark, the disciple and interpreter of Peter, did also hand down to us in writing what had been preached by Peter. Luke also, the companion of Paul, recorded in a book the Gospel preached by him. Afterwards John, the disciple of the Lord, who also had leaned upon his breast, did himself publish a Gospel during his residence at Ephesus in Asia. (Against Heresies 3:1:1)

Their dialect at that time was an Aramaic heavy influenced by Hebrew. Not the Hebrew of the Old Testament, not spoken at that time.  There is no indication that this was the same gospel that we now have in Greek.

I'd say "study" as well as worship.
